# TypeText is typing wrong

Tags: javascript, automated-tests, dom-events, watin

I'm having trouble typing a string in a input text. In some input texts it works perfectly but in others it doesn't.

For example a string has the value "master", but the result in the page is like "mastrer"

code:

```
    private void login(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        WatiN.Core.IE browser = new WatiN.Core.IE();
        browser.GoTo("http://184.10.01.30/lgggo");
        browser.TextField(Find.ById("igtxttxtUsuario")).TypeText("master");
        browser.TextField(Find.ById("igtxttxtSenha")).TypeText("master");
        browser.Element(Find.ById("btnEntrar")).Click();
    }
```

page:

> input name="txtUsuario" id="txtUsuario" type="hidden" value="mastrer"
>
> input name="txtUsuario_p" id="txtUsuario_p" type="hidden" value="mastrer"
>
> input class="splashInput" id="igtxttxtUsuario" style="width: 239px;" type="text" Object="[object Object]" _old="true" editID="txtUsuario" value="mastrer"
>
> input name="txtSenha" id="txtSenha" type="hidden" value="mastrer"/>
>
> input name="txtSenha_p" id="txtSenha_p" type="hidden" value="mastrer"/>
>
> input class="splashInput" id="igtxttxtSenha" style="width: 215px;" type="password" Object="[object Object]" _old="true" editID="txtSenha" value="mastrer"

While debugging I see the application mysteriously backing a position and putting that "r" between "t" and "e" which doen't exist.

Does anybody have any suggestion?

Comment: could you show the code that sets the name and value?

Comment: I have run into a similar problem. When I used typetext on some fields, it would type the text twice. I did not look into the root cause myself but I was told that it was occurring because of a javascript event that was tied up to the text field.

Comment: Exactly. In other field I send the text "001" and it's typed "001001". Unfortunately, I can't change the page.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use set attribute to a value...

```
browser.TextField(Find.ById("igtxttxtUsuario")).SetAttributeValue("value", "master");
```

This should work